# Segmenting Cheese Microstructure (Segmenting Circles)

Tags: image-processing, image-segmentation, image-analysis

I'm trying to get the internal geometry of cheese from images of its microstructure:

[image]

I tried the canny edge detector and otsu thresholding but neither of these worked very well. I'm guessing that I might need something more powerful but I'm not sure what as I'm new to the field of image processing.

In particular, I'd like to get the distribution of the distances between the pores and the spatial distribution of pore size from the image. Those are the two things I'm most interested in obtaining from the picture.

Comment: hm.... these pores do loop like little black circles, don't they? that would be my internet research keyword, *"detect circles in image"*.

Comment: or blob detection in skimage http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/plot_blob.html or in openCV https://www.learnopencv.com/blob-detection-using-opencv-python-c/ , 30 seconds in google.

Comment: In my youth, I read about some pattern recognition hardware using holograms and such.  Perhaps that work could be refitted the digital realm; which I presume you are in?  I sort of guess you would be looking for various sized circles?